# Send Data from firestore in nodejs to ajax call on client

Tags: node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a nodejs site. In my client side javascript, I have an ajax call where I am attempting to receive data from my firestore database.

However I cannot figure out a way to send the data retrieved from the firestore db to the client, because it is locked in a promise.

What I currently have on the server side is

```
app.get("/updateCalendar", (req, res) => {
    userId = req.query.userId;
    let eventCount = 0;
    let documents = {};
    let eventsRef = db.collection("Events");
    let query = eventsRef.where("userId", '==', 1).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        let documents = {};
        if(snapshot.empty) {
            console.log("No events");
            return;
        }
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            documents[eventCount] = doc.data();
            eventCount++;
        });
        return documents;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return err;
    });

    res.json(query)
});
```

Is there anyway that I can return the data from within the promise to the client side? Alternatively, is there another way to read from firestore that can allow me to send the data back to the client side.

Thanks

Comment: You should share more code, in particular the node.js code that responds to the ajax call. How do you implement it (independently of the Firestore part)? In other words, let's imagine that you want to send back data that is not "in a Promise", like a simple constant value. How would you do that in your environment?

Comment: That is 99% of the node js code that corresponds to the ajax call.

Comment: I edited it to show all of the code for the node js endpoint for the ajax call

Comment: So what is `snapshot` with its `.empty` property and `.forEach()` method?

Comment: And what does `doc.data()` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`get()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#get) method is asynchronous and returns a **[`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)** that resolves with the corresponding `QuerySnapshot`.

So you should return the data within the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method, as follows:

```
app.get("/updateCalendar", (req, res) => {
    userId = req.query.userId;
    let eventCount = 0;
    let documents = {};
    let eventsRef = db.collection("Events");
    let query = eventsRef.where("userId", '==', 1).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        let documents = {};
        if(snapshot.empty) {
            console.log("No events");
             throw new Error("No events");
        }
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            documents[eventCount] = doc.data();
            eventCount++;
        });
        res.json(documents);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send('Error');
    });


});
```